# White spaces while coming file into linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to copy contents of a file into a linked list in LIFO.my file has this data `QWERTY` but when I store it in a linked list it gets stored as- `YTREWQ` with some white spaces before `Y`.Where does additional spaces come from?Here is my code-
http://ideone.com/siR5dI

Comment: Are you concerned about the order in which items are stored/printed or just the whitespaces?

Comment: Just the whitespaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whitespace is the '\n' new line character or line terminator at the end of your file that gets added to the LIFO Queue.

```
$ ./LIFO.out inputfile 
0:Q
1:W
2:E
3:R
4:T
5:Y
6:

$ cat inputfile 
QWERTY
$
```

Above is the output I obtained by changing the following lines:

```
 int count = 0; // Add count initialization
    while(ch!=EOF)
     {
       printf("%d:%c\n",count++,ch);  // Print count to see how many chars are found in the file
       head1=insert(ch,head1);
       ch=getc(file1);
     }
```

---

To print the ascii values update the above snippet with:

```
printf("%d:%c(%d)\n",count++,ch,ch);
```

It gives me the following output:

```
0:Q(81)
1:W(87)
2:E(69)
3:R(82)
4:T(84)
5:Y(89)
6:
(10)
```

That 10 there is the ascii value of New Line Line Feed.

Comment: No, I have `QWERTY`in a single line with no other line in my text file

Comment: Can you use the updated code snippet I provided here and print the output. I am fairly certain that's the problem. Print ascii value of char to know for sure.

Comment: This is the output I am getting 
`0:Q
1:w
2:e
3:r
4:t
5:y
6:

7:

`
There is aso a newline before `7`.I dont know how to add the code properly in a comment.sorry

Comment: Great! This means there are a few extra characters provided in the input. Lets find out what they are. I will update the snippet which will print ascii value of the found input characters.

Comment: The ASCII value after `6:` is `10`.Now there is no `7` coming

Comment: How can I remove the line field?

Comment: That's the newline character at the end of line in the inputfile. Its a non-printable character so you don't see it but its there.

Comment: Do not press 'return' (aka 'enter') at the end of line in the input file you've created.

Answer (score 0):

```
the posted code does not cleanly compile.

if it did cleanly compile, then it would lose the 
contents of the 'head1' list pointer.

the main function 
should be confirming the value of 'argc' 
and displaying a 'usage' message if that value
is not 2

the code has a missive memory leak because 
the many malloc() areas are not passed to free()

for several reasons, the returned value from malloc() 9and family)
should not be cast

the returned value from malloc() needs to be checked
to assure successful operation

this line in insert(): 'temp->next=head;'
is placing the new node at the beginning of the array

this line in insert(): 'head=temp;'
is copying pointers
what is really need is something more like:
'*head = temp'


the insert() function is declared as returning a pointer
to a Node.  However, it does not do so.
that is one of the two compiler warnings raised.
(enable all warnings so you will see these problems)
(warnings should be corrected, not ignored)

the main() function has two parameter
and the first one 'argc' is not being used.
this one of the two compiler warnings raised.
properly checking/responding to the contents of
'argc' would correct that problem.

BTW: after 'head1' is set to point to the first Node
     you do not want to be ever changing it.
     this is usually a 'special case' 
     handled by the insert() function

the print() function fails to handle the case
of no Node in the linked list of Nodes

the main() function needs to check that the 
input char is either numeric or alpha
before calling the insert() function

as an assistance, the call to insert() should be passing
a double pointer that points to 'head1'
not the contents of 'head1'

suggest::
1) do not return a pointer from insert()
2) use insert( ch, **&head1 );
   where insert prototype is: void insert( char, struct Node ** )
3) check the number of command line parameters (using argc)
   and display a 'usage' messsage if there is a problem
4) the insert() function is inserting each node at the beginning
   of the linked list, which is why it is printing the data backwards
5) correct the print() function to allow for an empty linked list
6) code like it was C and not Pascal,  I.E.
   place the sub functions after main()
   and use prototype statement.
7) when a I/O statement fails, use 'perror()' function
   which will place statements to stderr,
   including the built in message that explains why the failure
8) there are reasons to use 'fgetc()' rather than 'getc()'
   including the returned value is an 'int', so EOF
   can actually be recognized
   (EOF is an 'int', not a 'char')
```